# Is "each and everyone" redundant?

Tags: meaning

Is saying "each and everyone" redundant?

Also, what is the difference between "each and everyone" and "each and every one"?

Thanks

Comment: Usually "each and every one", which is different from "each and everyone". Yes, it is redundant.

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with being redundant.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I'd have thought "redundant" means "contributes no additional information". But surely this form of "repetition" using an alternative term often conveys *emphasis*, which is a form of additional information.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Quite right. I think that, each and every time I hear it.

Comment: @HotLicks Don't you mean that there's nothing wrong with or in error about being redundant?

Comment: This community is so capricious.  Why on earth was this question downvoted?

Comment: @dennisdeems at a guess, I'd say it's because it looks like a drive-by "idle curiosity" question instead of a serious question in search of a serious answer.

Comment: In what contexts have you actually seen "each and everyone"?

Comment: @WS2: From which I assume you would be more likely to vehemently dismiss any suggestion from me along the lines of *Surely there must have been **some*** occasions when you heard it but **didn't** think that?*. You could make the point even more emphatically with *I **always** think that, each and every time I hear it*.

Comment: @ColinFine: At the heart of the rhetorical figure called merism is redundancy (e.g., lock, stock, and barrel; the whole kit and caboodle; from top to bottom; good and bad; searched high and low; heart and soul; each and every one).

Comment: People seem to be assuming that I intended a value judgment in describing it as "redundant". I didn't.

Comment: @fumblefingers not only is this an example of alternatives used for emphasis... It is alliterative alternatives redundantly repeated, enacting emphasis.  ☺

Comment: @Colin Fine: ***I*** certainly didn't assume you intended a value judgment - I take you for a staunch "descriptivist" and pragmatist, not a linguistic moraliser. But you didn't address my question, so I assume either you don't agree *"redundant" means "contributes no additional information"* or you don't consider the (optionally-exercised) inclusion of *emphasis* to be "additional information".

Comment: I think you're logic-chopping. It is redundant, and there can be good pragmatic and rhetorical reasons to be so.

Comment: The word *tautology* is a technical term from philosophy, meaning an argument with no premises.  While such arguments are usually simple self-evident truths, along the lines of "a man is a man" it is not exactly the same as what you mean, which is *redundant*, meaning the same thing stated twice or more.  I have edited to clarify.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for great comments and a very interesting discussion.

Answer (score 9):

"Each and every one" is a stock phrase where both "each" and "every" modify "one".  For that reason, it cannot be rephrased as "each and everyone" because that leaves the "each" dangling.

"Each one" typically has the same set of referents as "every one" which makes the phrase redundant.  However, the two phrases have slightly different emphases.  "Each one" emphasizes the individual, "every one" emphasizes the group.  So this phrase is really saying "each individual AND the group as a whole."

Comment: I find this the must succinct explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

*each and everyone -- ugly coordination of determiner and noun!

each [one] [of them] = each (member of the things) = each thing

every one [of them] = every (member of the things) = each thing

everyone = every (member of the people) = every person

each and every one [of them] -- redundancy used for emphasis

Comment: I'd argue that it's used as often for its cadency as it is for its emphasising property.